# Silence warning in PySAL weights command using geopandas df

Tags: gis, geospatial, pysal

I am calculating a weights matrix for a geopandas df. I know there is a keyword that will allow me to silence the island warning ([pysal doc](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/weights/weights.html)), but I get a keyword error when I try to use it...

```
wt = ps.weights.DistanceBand.from_dataframe(df, threshold=600000, binary=True, silent_island_warning=True)
```

Error...

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'silent_island_warning'
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of pysal are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.14.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The helper functions use the 'silent' argument, as opposed to the W object which uses the 'silent_island_warning' argument.

```
wt = ps.weights.DistanceBand.from_dataframe(df, threshold=600000, binary=True, silent=True)
```

See source: https://github.com/pysal/pysal/blob/master/pysal/weights/Distance.py